Automatically remove a child from its parent
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long bookId;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    // getter and setter removed for brevity

}

@Entity
public class Author implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Long authorId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    // getter and setter removed for brevity

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        getBooks().add(book);
        book.setAuthor(this);
    }

}

Consider the following test
@Test
public void manyToOneAndRemove() {
    System.out.println("Test");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Author author = new Author();
    author.setAuthorId(1L);
    author.setName("Deepak Kumar");
    em.merge(author);
    em.flush();

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookId(11L);
    book.setTitle("Welcome to CSS");
    em.merge(book);
    em.flush();

    Author author1 = em.find(Author.class, 1L);
    author1.addBook(book);
    em.merge(author1);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Author author2 = em.find(Author.class, 1L);

    System.out.println("Load 1:");
    author2.getBooks().forEach(b -> {
        System.out.printf("Book: (%s,%s)", b.getBookId(), b.getTitle());
        System.out.println();
    });

    Book aBook =  em.find(Book.class, 11L);
    em.remove(aBook);
    em.flush();

    Author author3 = em.find(Author.class, 1L);
    System.out.println("Load 2:");
    author3.getBooks().forEach(b -> {
        System.out.printf("Book: (%s,%s)", b.getBookId(), b.getTitle());
        System.out.println();
    });

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Author author4 = em.find(Author.class, 1L);
    System.out.println("Load 3:");
    author4.getBooks().forEach(b -> {
        System.out.printf("Book: (%s,%s)", b.getBookId(), b.getTitle());
        System.out.println();
    });

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}

The output will be
Test
Load 1:
Book: (11,Welcome to CSS)
Load 2:
Book: (11,Welcome to CSS)
Load 3:
Book: (11,Welcome to CSS)

Short explanation:

Save an author
Save a book and add the book to the books of the author
Load author in a new transaction to ensure the book is associated to the author correctly
Remove the book directly
Load the author to ensure the book is automatically removed from the books of the author

Step 5 is not true.
As you can see the book is not removed from it's parent. The author still has the reference to the book. As far as my understanding goes the book should be automatically removed from the collection in the author entity?!

so, the problem isn't step 5, it's rather step 3. Have you debugged the test? Checked that the book is actually found. Checked your DB to see if anything is actually removed? Either way, it seems a bit nasty to have an instance of Author for each Book, while for each instance of Author you have a set of Books

I checked step 3: The author knows the book and vice versa. I saw it in the debugger.

yes, the author knows the book and vice versa. Still, dodgy, I can understand having the author_id in the book, but the entire author .. but still, did you check that it actually delete something from the DB?

Instead of removing the book from the book table using em.remove(aBook), try removing the book from the Author's set and see if that removes the book in the books table or not.

@Stultuske This is not dodgy, it is common practice. Look here for example.

@Yousaf Yes, that works. But is not my question.

Ok, now I know why this is happening. I will write it down in an answer.

With your current code, have you tried adding cascade on Author in Book class?

This happens because author2 is loaded just before the removal of the book. author2 still has the book in it's collection and is already in the persistence conctext. As soon as the transaction ends, the book will be flushed to the DB again. If I remove the find-method of author2 everything works fine.
As Vlad Mihalcea mentioned here it is a best practice to always synchronize both sides of an entity relationship, no matter if it’s @OneToMany, @OneToOne or @ManyToMany.
He is explaining it this way:

However, we still need to have both sides in sync as otherwise, we break the Domain > Model relationship consistency, and the entity state transitions are not guaranteed
to work unless both sides are properly synchronized.
If a bidirectional association is out of sync and only the child can
reference a parent while the parent wouldn’t contain the child in its
collection, then you risk exposing your model to tricky bugs where you
make the wrong decision based on the presence or the absence of a
child in the parent’s children collection.
And, in the context of Hibernate, only synchronized bidirectional associations are
guaranteed to be persisted properly in the database. Even if you observe on a specific Hibernate version that it works even when the association is out of sync, it’s not guaranteed that it will work if you upgrade to a newer version of Hibernate.
For these reasons, the Post entity defines the addComment and removeComment entity state synchronization methods.


As suggested in @Chris311's answer (see the last sentence of the Vlad Mihalcea quote), it's good practice to have add/remove methods that manage both sides of the relationship.  It's in our style guide that you set the child's relationship before the parent's.  Also, our style guide stipulates that you should access the books collection directly, and not through the Hibernate-proxied getBooks() method when you are working directly with a class' owned members.  (That is, set the author before setting adding it to the collection of books.  I forget the entire rationale, but there are some weird edge cases that this helps to avoid.)
public void addBook(Book book) {
    book.setAuthor(this);
    books.add(book);
}
public void removeBook(Book book) {
    book.setAuthor(null);
    books.remove(book);
}

